# Checklist for deployed web applications & SSRS and SSIS services hosted if the IP changes for windows server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, windows-server-2008, ssis-2008

We have windows server which is being shifted to another location due to which the IP would change for it. 
It is a physical server with 2 virtual servers created on it-one being used as web and the other as DB. Both of them appropriate ports opened to be able to communicate with each other.
*We have 15+ web applications hosted in its IIS.
*We have SSRS configured on it on which are hosted 20+ SSRS reports.
*DB server also has SSIS packages running on the DB server.

Because of the IP config what all configurations need to be checked and altered for business as usual.

What I can think of is the following-
IP needs to be changed in connection strings in web.config of all web applications.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Because of the IP change of server what all configurations need to be checked and altered for business as usual?:) apology if I wasn't clear.

Comment: How can we tell you that? We have no idea what applications are running on said server and how they work.

Comment: Just wanted common configuration (not specific to applications) check for ASP.NET/IIS settings and services like SSRS and SSIS.

Comment: There is nothing like that.